# Segmentation error when swapping 2D array elements with pointers

Tags: c, initialization, undefined-behavior, swap, dereference

I am trying to swap 2 values in a matrix - the value in the 1st row, 2nd column ***(5)*** and the value in the 4th row, 3rd column ***(2)***.

Once compiled, the program terminates due to a segmentation error when I try to assign the value of `*temp`. I have the code attached below.

```c
void swap(float *y)
{
    float *temp;
    *temp=*(y+1);
    *(y+1)=*(y+11);
    *(y+11)=*temp;
}

void main()
{
    float a[5][3]={{7,5,4},{2,7,4},{7,5,2},{8,4,2},{9,5,2}}, *aptr=&a[0][0];
    swap(aptr);
}
```

I am sorry for any glaring mistakes in my code, I am new to C and I'm trying to grasp the concept of pointers.

Comment: The compiler should be warning that `temp` has not been initialised. `*temp = *(y + 1);` is trying to copy to an interdetermine location. Did you mean simply `float temp; temp = *(y + 1);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer temp is uninitialized. So dereferencing the pointer results in undefined behavior.

Instead you need to use an object of the type float.

```
void swap(float *y)
{
    float temp;
    temp=*(y+1);
    *(y+1)=*(y+11);
    *(y+11)=temp;
}
```